# State controller class singleton in .Net Maui

Tags: c#, maui

I have a need to create a singleton in .Net Maui that will save the state of the active user profile to provide it to all the ViewModels to work off of.  This data will be used to display different user data (same SQL DB and methods though) depending on the selected profile.  I'd also like to pull license state with the same process along with a few other stateful variables.

In addition, I'd like these to be observable so the ViewModels can react when these variables change.

In a regular app, I would just create a static class and refer to it.  But in .Net Maui, it looks like I need to inject that into the app.shell / MauiProgram.

This is the initial singleton I started working with:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Controller
{
    public sealed partial class MyAppSingleton : ObservableObject
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<MyAppSingleton> _lazy = new Lazy<MyAppSingleton>(() => new MyAppSingleton());

        public static MyAppSingleton Instance
        { 
            get { return _lazy.Value; } 
        }

        private UserProfile _activeProfile;

        [ObservableProperty]
        public int currentProfile;

        public MyAppSingleton() 
        { 
        }

        public void SetActiveProfile(UserProfile incomingProfile)
        { 
            ActiveProfile = incomingProfile;
        }

    }
}
```

Then in MauiProgram.cs I have this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ConfigurePage>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<ConfigurePageViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyAppSingleton>();
```

But if I try to access the singleton in any of the ViewModels like this:

```
MyAppSingleton.SetActiveProfile(userProfile);
```

I has a procompile error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MyAppSingleton.SetActiveProfile'

I haven't spent any time building interfaces, but I don't think that's what I need here as the backend isn't changing; I'm not reading the data from difference places for example.

So, I'm missing something but I'm not understanding how to instantiate a singleton for all the ViewModels.

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: The error occurs because you are calling the `SetActiveProfile` method in a static context. In C#, static methods or properties can only directly access other static members, while instance methods require an instance of the class to be called. So, you can try to first create an instance of `MyAppSingleton` and then call the `SetActiveProfile` method, like `MyAppSingleton.Instance.SetActiveProfile(userProfile);`.

Comment: Register to DI container and having a static Instance property and try to call a non-static method as a static one? You should choose one of this three ways. I recommend to use the container for injection